# setup field name during serialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have class ObjectId. It return from restcontroller method createObject.
As a result I get json with id

```
{
  "objectId" : 1
}
```

class is here

```
class ObjectId {

    @JsonProperty("objectId")
    public long getObjectId() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And I have another class:

```
class SuperObject {

  @JsonUnwropped
  ObjectId superObjectId;
}
```

I want that after serialization I have got

```
{
  "superObjectId" : 1
}
```

But I got

```
{
  "objectId" : 1
}
```

Is it possible to setup serializer to return superObjectId?
I know that @JsonUnwropped has prefix, but using that I got
superobjectId, not superObjectId

Comment: do you mean `@JsonProperty("superObjectId")`

Comment: @tknkrtl, yep.
If I use @JsonProperty("superObjectId") and delete \@JsonUnwrapped, I get
{superObjectId: {"objectId":1}}, If I use \@JsonPropperty and \@JsonUnwrapper property don't serialize at all

Comment: try @JsonUnwrapped annotation on SuperObject class, and @JsonProperty("superObjectId") on getObjectId method                                                                            
  ` @JsonUnwrapped                                                                                               
   class SuperObject {

 
  ObjectId superObjectId;
} `

Comment: JsonUnwrapped doesn't applicable to type, so I can't  annotate class by it